# Assigning value to element in array changes other variable

Tags: python

I've been studying for a computing contest and while I was working on a seemingly trivial problem I've experienced some unexpected behaviour. I'm sure the answer is very simple but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

The problem is: https://dmoj.ca/problem/ccc14s1

Here's my program:

```
import math

K = int(input())
m = int(input())
r_i = []

for i in range(m):
    r_i.append(int(input()))

friends = [x+1 for x in range(K)]
print(r_i)
for j in r_i:
    instances = int(math.floor(friends[-1] / j))
    for k in range(instances):
        friends[j*(k+1) - 1] = -1

for n in friends:
    if(n != -1):
        print(n)
```

The problem is that after one time through the loop `for j in r_i`, `instances` evaluates to -1. I've found that removing the line `friends[j*(k+1) - 1] = -1` will fix the problem but I can't see why assigning the value -1 to an element in `friends` would affect the value of `instances` on the next iteration.

Comment: You know what `friends[-1]` means?

Comment: It means the last element in friends, correct?

Comment: Take the first sample input, `10 2 2 3`. At the first loop you set `friends[9] = -1`, and `friends[9]` is equivalent to `friends[-1]`, that's the reason.

Comment: Ahhh. So It's really evaluating to friends[friends.index(-1)] the second time?

Comment: I will use K/j instead

Comment: I added an answer. Try if it helps.

Comment: You were assuming `friends[-1]` would always tell you the number of remaining unremoved friends, not just on the first iteration where it happens to have the value K. But it doesn't, because you then assign -1 to it. Give some thought to how you 'remove' friends (`.pop()`? assign to -1? something else?), and hence how you count the remaining unremoved friends (list comprehension?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the sample input from the link you've given:

```
10
2
2
3
```

At the first loop:

```
for j in r_i:
    instances = int(math.floor(friends[-1] / j))
    for k in range(instances):
        friends[j*(k+1) - 1] = -1
```

You're setting `friends` to

```
[1, -1, 3, -1, 5, -1, 7, -1, 9, -1]
                                ^^
```

So at the next loop, when you try to get `friends[-1]`, you're getting the value pointed out above. No doubt it's `-1`.

You should clear out all `-1` s after setting them once:

```
for j in r_i:
    instances = int(math.floor(friends[-1] / j))
    for k in range(instances):
        friends[j*(k+1) - 1] = -1
    friends = [i for i in friends if i != -1]
```